# Proving $[G,C^n(G)] = [C^n(G),G]$ and $C^{n}(G) \trianglelefteq G$

Tags: group-theory

I'm working on central series.

> I would like to prove that if we define $$C^1(G)=G     ,\;     C^{n+1}(G)=[G,C^n(G)],$$ then
>   $C^n(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $C^{n+1}(G)=[C^n(G),G]$ for all $n≥1$.

Here is what I tried.

1. For $n=1$, this is trivial. For $n≥2$, let $x \in G$, and $gcg^{-1}c^{-1} \in C^n(G)$ with $c \in C^{n-1}(G) \trianglelefteq G$ by induction hypothesis.
   Then $x(gcg^{-1}c^{-1})x^{-1} = xgcg^{-1}x^{-1}xc^{-1}x^{-1} \in C^{n-1}(G)$. I don't know how to continue.
2. I tried to do it by induction on $n$, using to previous point $1$., but I failed to show $[G,[C^{n-1}(G),G]]=[[G,C^{n-1}(G)],G]$.

As a "bonus" question, are there some nice (i.e. non trivial) sufficient conditions on subgroups $A,B ≤ G$ such that $[A,B]=[B,A]$ ? For instance, $G$ finite and $A,B$ normal subgroups of $G$ ? This is just out of curiosity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually (almost) solved it yourself. I'll just put it together for you:

If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$, then $[A,B]$ denotes the subgroup of $G$ generated by all $[a,b]:= aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ for $a\in A$, $b\in B$. Since we have $[a,b]^{-1} = (aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1} = bab^{-1}a^{-1} = [b,a]$, it follows that $[A,B] = [B,A]$.

If $A$ and $B$ are normal in $G$, then also $[A,B]$ is normal in $G$: Given $a\in A$, $b\in B$ and $x\in G$, we have $xax^{-1}\in A$ and $xbx^{-1}\in B$ and hence
\begin{align*}
x[a,b]x^{-1} &= [xax^{-1},xbx^{-1}] \in [A,B].
\end{align*}
Since $[A,B]$ is generated by the $[a,b]$, it follows that $[A,B]$ is normal.